# Load javascript on page load using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have some working code (jQuery/Javascript) that makes a call to an API and submits data to it. The same service then returns a success or failure message depending on whether the data was inserted into the API db. The below works flawlessly when loaded in the browser.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var groupType = getParameterByName('group').trim();

            if (groupType == 'm') {
                groupId = 'ICM.RealLife.Mobile';
            } else if (groupType == 'd') {
                groupId = 'ICM.RealLife.Desktop';
            }

            var email = getParameterByName('email').trim();
            var mobileTel = getParameterByName('mobile').trim();
            var panelistId = mobileTel;
            var password = 'icm001';
            var locale = 'en';

            alert('email=' + email + '\n\nMobile=' + mobileTel + '\n\nGroup=' + groupId);

            if (mobileTel != '' && email != '' && groupId != '') {
                //Build up querystring to pass to API
                var dataString = "panelistId=" + (encodeURIComponent('+') + mobileTel) + "&groupId=" + groupId + "&emailAddress=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&locale=" + locale + "&mobileNumber=" + (encodeURIComponent('+') + mobileTel) + "";
                //var apiResult;
                //send to API
                $.getJSON('https://www.analyzeme.net/api/server/prereg/?', dataString + '&callback=?', function (getResult) {
                    //apiResult = JSON.stringify(getResult);
                    //alert(apiResult);
                });
            //} else {
            //    alert('Incorrect parameters!');
            }
        });
```

I now have to get this working using a 1x1 tracking pixel using aspx like below;

```
<img src="http://www.somedomain.com/pixel.aspx?email=email@email.com&mobile=+441111222222&group=d" width="1" height="1"/>
```

**BUT**, I do not know how to get my JavaScript to fire in the asp.net page when it is hit? I know I need to do something with RegisterStartupScript but how do I get all that JS into it and how do I get it to fire when the page is hit. I know how to return an img/gif using response headers, so I am cool with that.

Help greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the JS function from your Page_Load event in code behind. This will fire every time the page is loaded.

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", true);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    //Code you want to run from document.ready
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I totally forgot to mark this as resolved.